# Dynamic Predicate - accessing its content

Tags: list, dynamic, prolog, predicate

I have a dynamic predicate

```
:- dynamic example/1.
```

Let's say, I decide to initialise it to a pair of value within a list

```
initialise_example(X,Y):- assert(example([(X,Y)])).
```

So in the console, I would type :

```
| ?- initialise_example(leftValue, rightValue).
```

This would then save to the database a fact:

```
example([leftValue,rightValue]).
yes
```

Now my question is, how do I extract, say, the **leftValue** atom in order to do
some manipulation with it? Assuming that *leftValue* and *rightValue* are part of a big database composed of multiple atoms.

EDIT:

Let's say I have a fact that is as follows:

```
example([(leftValue,rightValue),(leftValue2,rightValue2),(leftValue3,rightValue3), . . . , (leftValueN,rightValueN)]).
```

How would I access the head of the list that composes the fact above.

```
example([H|T]).
```

would be used in another predicate, but it would store the whole data of `example()` until the other predicate finishes it's process. Thus not letting me use updated data of the `example()` within that other predicate.

Comment: Why would you save something as `example([left, right])` when you could just save it as `example(left, right)`? What's the purpose of using the list construct and saving it as a list of just one element?

Comment: so i have a list of pairs `example([(left,right),(up,down),...,(Xn,Yn)]`

Comment: Generally it's better to have separate facts, `example(x1, y1).` and `example(x2, y2).` etc. But your problem statement is very generic and doesn't indicate anything at all about multiple values or how you intend to use them.

Comment: What you show, or something close: `example([H|_])`, is exactly how you'd get the head of the list from the data. It's a little unclear what else you might be asking here. Perhaps an example...